# Custom DatePicker Button. Custom Components in Android

Tags: android, button, android-custom-view

I am trying to create a custom date picker button component.  The button displays the date and when clicked it opens the date picker dialog box.  I have implemented this method using the Android Dev Docs/Tutorial however I have 2 of them in my code and I figured it would be better to create a custom class called DateButton which would clean up my code a bit.  So whenever I need a similar button I can create a declare a DateButton in my XML.  Anyways this is my first time creating a custom view and I need some help whenever I try to add my custom button to my layout I get an error:

```
error! ClassNotFoundException: android.app.DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener
```

Here is what I want the button to look at (very simple)

[image]

and when it is clicked it will pop up the built in android datepicker dialog:

[image]

Here is my current code for this custom datebutton:

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;


public class DateButton extends Button implements OnClickListener, OnDateSetListener {

     private static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
private OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

public DateButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public DateButton(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
    super(arg0, arg1);
}

public DateButton(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
    super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
}

private DatePickerDialog showDialog(int dateDialogId) {
    return new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
            mDateSetListener,
            mYear, mMonth, mDay);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
        int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    mYear = year;
    mMonth = monthOfYear;
    mDay = dayOfMonth;
    updateDisplay();
}

private void updateDisplay() {
    this.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(pad(mMonth + 1)).append("/")
            .append(pad(mDay)).append("/")
            .append(mYear).append(" "));
}

//if single digit append "0" to the number
private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
        return String.valueOf(c);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
   }
    }
```

EDIT: I'm still running into trouble anyone have any examples of something similar to this?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `showDialog` method to:

```
private showDialog() {
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
            this, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Also add initialize code for `mYear, mMonth, mDay`.

Comment: what would I call in the onClick?

Comment: @IZI_Shadow_IZI sorry for previous code, I have confused with `Activity`. Check new one.

Comment: same error message with the showDialog method. still getting classNotFound